# Namespaces declared by a theme/plugin should start with the theme/plugin prefix. Found: "eustatos\test_plugin"

Tags: plugins, namespace

I want to use namespace in my plugin. And I have error after PHP_Code_Sniffer check.

> Namespaces declared by a theme/plugin should start with the theme/plugin prefix. Found: "`eustatos\test_plugin`". (`WordPress.NamingConventions.PrefixAllGlobals.NonPrefixedNamespaceFound`)

My folder structure:

```
.
└── test-plugin
    ├── composer.json
    ├── phpcs.xml
    ├── test-plugin.php
    └── vendor
```

```php
// test-plugin.php
<?php

namespace eustatos\test_plugin;
```

`phpcs.xml` content from [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/develop/phpcs.xml.dist.sample)
How I must name namespace?

Answer (score 2):

At first, we need to update `phpcs.xml`.

Let's replace `"my_prefix"` with your plugin name (then, assuming `"eustatos"`):

```xml
    <rule ref="WordPress.NamingConventions.PrefixAllGlobals">
        <properties>
            <property name="prefixes" type="array">
                <element value="eustatos"/>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </rule>
```

Then, you can use namespace start with `eustatos` in project PHP file.

ex:

```php
namespace eustatos\test_plugin;
```

#### cf.

[Customizable sniff properties · WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards Wiki](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/wiki/Customizable-sniff-properties#naming-conventions-prefix-everything-in-the-global-namespace)

> To execute this check one or more prefixes which should be considered valid must be provided via the $prefixes property in your custom ruleset or via the command-line.
>
> If this property is not set, this sniff will not run.
>
> ```xml
> <rule ref="WordPress.NamingConventions.PrefixAllGlobals">
>   <properties>
>       <property name="prefixes" type="array">
>           <element value="my_prefix"/>
>           <element value="tgmpa"/>
>       </property>
>
>   </properties>
> </rule>
> ```